# Can phone calls have metadata like "forwarded by"?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm thinking of writing a call-screening application using the [Twilio API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml).

When a call comes in, my application would decide, based on various rules, whether to ring my phone or send the caller to voicemail.

So calls would flow like:

```
                                       ┌─────────┐
                                    ┌─▶│Voicemail│
┌──────┐  ┌─────────────┐  ┌──────┐ │  └─────────┘
│Caller│─▶│Twilio Number│─▶│My App│─┤
└──────┘  └─────────────┘  └──────┘ │  ┌─────────┐
                           depending└─▶│My Phone │
                          on rules...  └─────────┘
```

Ideally, I could do both of these things:

1. My phone **only** rings for calls that were routed through my app
2. When my phone does ring, I see the **original caller's** caller ID

For #1, I could ask my carrier to block all other calls, or could maybe write some Android code to run on my phone, but in any case, I'd need to know "this came from my app."

Are both of these things possible? Eg, can a phone call have metadata saying where it was forwarded from, or is Caller ID the only info I can get?

**Can I pass along both the original caller ID and the fact that the call came through my app?**

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'll start with #2 as that's easiest. The default behaviour of [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial), which you use to forward calls made to a Twilio number onto your own number, is to make the caller ID that of the original caller ID. So you should see this happen in Twilio already.

For #1, there's no way that I know of to send on metadata as part of a call with Twilio and then access that metadata on the phone level to block the calls.

I don't know if you could do this at carrier level. I would guess that Twilio sends particular SIP headers which the carrier could look for, but I don't have more information on that.

You could, with Twilio, at least let yourself know that a call has come from your app rather than directly to your number. You can use what is called a ["whisper"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/call-whisper). This allows you to give yourself a message, say "This is a call from your app" before connecting the call. You can achieve this by forwarding the call to your number using `<Dial>` with a [`<Number>` noun and setting a `url` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-url). The `url` should point to another endpoint that returns TwiML with your message, you can use [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) for that.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for responding! The "whisper" is helpful, but isn't ideal because the phone still rings, and I still have to pick up before I know it's a call I don't want. Is there any other way to send phone calls that would allow attaching some metadata - eg, send a VOIP call to a custom Android app, which could examine the incoming call and decide whether to ring?

Comment: @philnash I'm curious if #2 will still work as you described if we add an extra step.  Imagine a scenario similar to the above except instead of "Caller -> Twilio Number", the flow is "Caller -> Phone Number w/ Call Forwarding turned on -> Call Forwarded to Twilio Number".  Does the metadata get passed along when a call is forwarded to the twilio number?

Comment: @philnash to be clear in my previous comment, I was referring to setting up call forwarding from my cell phone # to a twilio number using the tactic described in this article: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2009/01/using-conditional-call-forwarding-and-twilio.html

Comment: @BFar I am afraid I do not know and I'm not in the US to test this. Best thing to do is likely try it out yourself with your own number.